Proof for relation between functions
For start lets define
$\sigma(d)$: the sum of divisors of d, with $d \in \mathbb{Z}$
$\tau(d)$: the number of divisors of d, with $d \in \mathbb{Z}$
I want to prove that,
$\sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) =  \sum_{d|n} d\tau(d) $
My idea is based on,
$\sigma(d) = \sum_{t|d} t$ and $\tau(d) = \sum_{t|d} 1$, so I wrote:
$ \sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = \sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d} \sum_{t|d} t = 
\sum_{d|n} \sum_{t|d} \frac{n}{d} t$
Changing the summation order (I will use the notation '':'' to say ''such that'')
$\sum_{t|n} \sum_{d|n \,:\, t|d} \frac{n}{d} t$
since t divides d then $d = kt$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Also since $kt | n$ and $t | n$ then $k | \frac{n}{t}$
$\sum_{t|n} \sum_{k | \frac{n}{t}} \frac{n}{kt} t = \sum_{t|n} n \sum_{k | \frac{n}{t}} \frac{1}{k} $
From here I dont know how proceed, i wanted to end up on someting like $ \sum_{t|n} \frac{n}{t} \sum_{k | \frac{n}{t}} 1 = \sum_{t|n} \frac{n}{t} \tau(\frac{n}{t}) = \sum_{d|n} d \tau(d)$, but I have not found a way.
Any ideas of how to proceed or any other way I can prove that $\sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) =  \sum_{d|n} d\tau(d)$ ? (If it is possible avoid the use of Dirichlet product)

if you have two multiplicative functions that agree for $1,$  all primes, and all prime powers, then they agree.

Dirichlet product $\star$ of Arithmetic functions $f$ and $g$ is defined by
$$f\star g  = \sum\limits_{d|n}f(d)g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right).$$
You might be aware that $\star$ is commutative and associative. Suppose, I introduce new functions $p_0(n) =1$ and $p_1(n)=n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Note that I can write now,
$$\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = p_1 \star \sigma (n).$$
But $$\sigma = \sum\limits_{d|n}d = p_1\star p_0 (n).$$
Thus,
$$\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = p_1\star (p_1\star p_0) (n)$$
Now, using the  associative properties of Dirichlet function, I may write,
$$\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = (p_1\star p_1)\star p_0 (n). \tag{1}$$
But observe that
$$p_1\star p_1 (n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}d = n \sum\limits_{d|n}1 = p_1\tau (n). $$
Thus, finally, using this in $(1)$, we would arrive at
$$\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = p_1\tau \star p_0 (n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}p_1(d)\tau(d)p_0\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = \sum\limits_{d|n}d\tau(d).$$
$\textbf{Edit.}$
I leave it to you to think of why things happen so as written below.
Observe that
$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = \sum_{ab=n} a\sigma(b) = \sum_{ab=n}a\sum_{cd=b}d.$$
The simply turns out to be
$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) =\sum_{adc=n} ad.$$
Observe that $ad$ is a divisor of $n$. In other word, for each divisor $k$ of $n$, find out all possible expression of the form $k=ad$. How many possibilities we can have for each $k$? Clearly, $\tau(k)$. And the summand thus contains $\tau(k)$ copies of $k$. Thus, we may rewrite the above as
$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = \sum_{kc=n}k\tau(k) = \sum_{d|n}d\tau(d).$$

Thanks for the suggestion but I want a solution without the use of Dirichlet product as I would like to emphasize different aspects/properties with the final solution.

Okay. I could have avoided, in fact, Dirichlet product, by simply playing with symbolic manipulations by imitating the proof of associativity of Dirichlet product.

If it is not troubling, would you mind providing this solution then? I want to solve it with use of division properties/prime number properties etc , more basic concepts.

I have edited. Please check the edit.
